# Undefined reference to function errors, using C and C++ together

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have run into a problem while using C and C++ code together. The **'make'** command returns "Undefined reference to function" for all functions in **SPConfig.c** and **SPLogger.c**, when called from **SPImageProc.cpp**
**#include** sections of these relevant files are given below:

**SPLogger.c**

```
#include "SPLogger.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
```

**SPConfig.h**

```
#ifndef SPCONFIG_H_
#define SPCONFIG_H_

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SPLogger.h"
//Functions definitions
#endif /* SPCONFIG_H_ */
```

**SPConfig.c**

```
#include "SPConfig.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
```

**SPImageProc.h**

```
#ifndef SPIMAGEPROC_H_
#define SPIMAGEPROC_H_
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <vector>

extern "C" {
#include "SPConfig.h"
#include "SPPoint.h"
}

namespace sp {
//Class and function definitions
}
```

**SPImageProc.cpp**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <cstdio>
#include "SPImageProc.h"
extern "C" {
#include "SPLogger.h"
}
```

**Makefile**

```
CC = gcc
CPP = g++
#put all your object files here
OBJS = main.o SPImageProc.o SPPoint.o 
#The executabel filename
EXEC = SPCBIR
INCLUDEPATH=/usr/local/lib/opencv-3.1.0/include/
LIBPATH=/usr/local/lib/opencv-3.1.0/lib/
LIBS=-lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_features2d \
-lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core


CPP_COMP_FLAG = -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra \
-Werror -pedantic-errors -DNDEBUG

C_COMP_FLAG = -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra \
-Werror -pedantic-errors -DNDEBUG

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CPP) $(OBJS) -L$(LIBPATH) $(LIBS) -o $@
main.o: main.cpp #put dependencies here!
    $(CPP) $(CPP_COMP_FLAG) -I$(INCLUDEPATH) -c $*.cpp
#a rule for building a simple c++ source file
#use g++ -MM SPImageProc.cpp to see dependencies
SPImageProc.o: SPImageProc.cpp SPImageProc.h SPConfig.h SPPoint.h SPLogger.h
    $(CPP) $(CPP_COMP_FLAG) -I$(INCLUDEPATH) -c $*.cpp
#a rule for building a simple c source file
#use "gcc -MM SPPoint.c" to see the dependencies

SPPoint.o: SPPoint.c SPPoint.h 
    $(CC) $(C_COMP_FLAG) -c $*.c
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(EXEC)
```

**Some of Makefile errors:**

```
SPImageProc.o: In function `sp::ImageProc::initFromConfig(sp_config_t*)':
SPImageProc.cpp:(.text+0xc8): undefined reference to `spConfigGetPCADim'
SPImageProc.cpp:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to `spLoggerPrintError'
SPImageProc.cpp:(.text+0x12c): undefined reference to `spConfigGetNumOfImages'
```

I have implemented the functions in their respective C and CPP files. I have tried a lot to fix it myself and looked it up on Stack Overflow for similar problems but couldn't find a solution. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not linking `SPLogger.o` and `SPConfig.o`

Or even compiling them for that matter.

You need to add make rules for `SPLogger.o` and `SPConfig.o` similar to `SPImageProc.o` and you need to add them to `OBJS`.

Comment: Thank you so much for figuring it out. I have edited the makefile to link SPLogger.o and SPConfig.o. It is compiling now. Thanks again.